# How to loop an array of integers and save both positive and negative into another array?

Tags: c, arrays, loops

For example an array: `{1, 2, 3}`

How do I make a program that loops this array to get an output of `{1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3}`?

I tried doing something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n = 3;
    int arr[3] = {1, 2, 3};
    int result[6];


    int i, j, k;
    for(i = 0; i < n*2; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            for(k = 0; k < 2; k++)
            {
                if((i+1) % 2 != 0)
                {
                    result[i] = arr[j];
                }
                else if((i+1) % 2 == 0)
                {
                    result[i] = -arr[j];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < n*2; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", result[i]);
    }
}
```

But it only outputs `{3, -3, 3, -3, 3, -3}`
I thought my logic was perfect xD . Can anyone help?

Comment: You should do some debugging.

Comment: Your code won't compile since `a0_over_a_size` and `possible_roots` are undefined.

Comment: Oops. I renamed the variables when I put the code in the post. I might not have been able to change it earlier. Imma edit it noe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple implementation: just store positive and negative values.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n = 3;
    int arr[3] = {1, 2, 3};
    int result[6];

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        result[i * 2] = arr[i];
        result[i * 2 + 1] = -arr[i];
    }

    for(i = 0; i < n * 2; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", result[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh. Why didn't I think of that. I had too complicated thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

This block seems to work:

```
    int src[] = { 1, 2, 3};

    int dest[(sizeof(src) / sizeof(int)) * 2];

    int destCount = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(src) / sizeof(int); i++) {
        dest[destCount++] = abs(src[i]);
        dest[destCount++] = -(abs(src[i]));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(src) / sizeof(int)) * 2; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", dest[i]);
    }
```

I put in abs() calls to make sure you get a positive number followed by a negative number. If this isn't what you want, then just get rid of them.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you just want output you could do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n = 3;
    int arr[3] = {1, 2, 3};

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
        printf("%d ",-1*arr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```